# Differences between Micheline and Michelson

Tags: michelson, micheline

What is the difference between Micheline and Michelson? Is Micheline a subset of Michelson?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Micheline is the concrete syntax of Michelson.

https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html

The concrete syntax means that it is the part of language in which Michelson is actually written and doesn't deal with semantics (evaluation, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I have recently written a documentation page for Micheline that might help you better understand what it is: https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/micheline.html